# Quitar archivo de un input file

Tags: html, html5, input-file

Como le hago para poder por medio de un botón, que en el input file se quite el archivo seleccionado al picarle a un botón.

```
<div class="input-group-prepend">
 <button id="botonBorrar" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" >Borrar</button>
</div>
<div class="custom-file" style="margin-right: 10px;">
 <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile03" onclick="document.getElementById('inputGroupFile03').click();" onchange="document.getElementById('labelArchivo').innerText = document.getElementById('inputGroupFile03').files[0]['name'];">
 <label id="labelArchivo" class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile03">Adjuntar archivo</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta con poner su value en "".

Ej:

```
document.getElementById("inputGroupFile03").value = "";
```

Esto podrías ponerlo dentro de una función que se dispare en el click del botón que deseas que haga el reset del input file.

---

Otra opción podría ser wrapear todo en una etiqueta form (en caso de que aun no lo esté) y tener un botón o elemento que en el onclick u onClick dependiendo de con que estés trabajando  haga algo así:

```
onClick="this.form.reset()"
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo mucho.

Comment: Me alegro mucho!
Quedo a las órdenes.